# Joining 2 tables with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables :

```
Table User => id, name

Table Tag  => id, tag_name, used, status

Table User_tag => id, user_id, tag_id, inserted_at
```

*Where user_id references to id field of USER table, and tag_id references to id field on TAG table)

My question is : 
I would like to select all tags and sort it based on the how many times the tag appear in user_tag, if no appear at all on user_tag, sort it based on field USED on TAG table.

I have try like this :

```
SELECT tag.*, COUNT(user_tag.id) as number_of_appear FROM tag 
  LEFT JOIN user_tag ON tag.id = user_tag.tag_id 
  WHERE tag.status = 1 AND user_tag.user_id = 2 
  GROUP BY tag.tag 
  ORDER BY number_of_appear DESC, tag.used DESC
```

In this case, there is no user_id = 2 in user_tag table. That's why it return 0 record. I want it still return a tag_name even though there is no record on the user_tag table. If a tag id not appear at all, sort it based tag.used field.

My purpose is to create an option of tags for user, but i want to sort it from the most often used by THE USER. so user does not have to scroll to search their favorite tags.

anybody can help me ?

Comment: Thanks soul for correcting my question T.T .. Still new to stack overflow ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tag.name, 
    (SELECT count(*) as amount
     FROM user_tag
     JOIN tag ON tag.id = user_tag.tag_id
     WHERE tag.status = 1 AND user_tag.user_id = 2 AND tag.id = t.id
    ) as total
FROM tag as t
ORDER BY total
```

Comment: cannot, it returns no record, since no record on USER_TAG table that have user_id = 2. I want even though there is no record in USER_TAG table that have user_id = 2, it still return a row so i can get the tag_name

Comment: thats why i didn't understand why you were wanting a where clause

Comment: My purpose is to create an option of tags for user, but i want to sort it from the most often used by THE USER. so user does not have to scroll to search their favorite tags. So the SELECT query have to return ALL TAGS name, sorted from the most often used by user.

Comment: I need the WHERE clause to calculate how many time the user use A TAG, let say Marcel used : tag "Culinary" 2 times, tag "Hobby" 5 times, tag "sport" 0 times. It have to return this -> Hobby, Culinary, Sport (In this order)